# How do i auto resize the buttons as well when the screen resizes to smaller screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css, autoresize

```css
   .beaker {
        max-width:100%;
        height: auto;
        width: auto;

    }
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-1">
   <img id="img" width="60px" src="images/a1.png" class="img-rounded" />
</div>
<div class="col-xs-2">
   <br/>
   <br/>
   <button id="upper" type="button" class="btn btn-primary beaker">IP > Ksp</button>
   <br/>
   <br/>
   <br/>
   <br/>
   <br/>
   <br/>
   <br/> 
   <br/>
   <button id="middle" type="button" class="btn btn-primary beaker">IP = Ksp</button>
   <br/>
   <br/>
   <br/> 
   <br/>
   <br/>
   <br/>
   <br/> 
   <br/>
   <button id="reset" type="button" class="btn btn-primary beaker">IP < Ksp</button>
</div>
```

Is there any way i could also make the buttons auto resize when screen gets smaller with the exact same spot as i put in before screen resize. I have tried putting the width to 100% but it still doesnt work. I think its because of the bootstrap grid column that is why the buttons doesnt resize at all. PLease help.

Comment: make use of `@media` queries

Answer (score 1):

Use `media queries`. you can resize the buttons when the screen gets smaller. This is one way.

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .btn {
    padding: 2px 4px;
    font-size: 80%;
    line-height: 1;
    border-radius: 3px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 992px) {
  .btn {
    padding: 4px 9px;
    font-size: 90%;
    line-height: 1.2;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-xs-1">

  <img id="img" width="60px" src="images/a1.png" class="img-rounded" />


</div>
<div class="col-xs-2">
  <br/>
  <br/>


  <button id="upper" type="button" class="btn btn-primary beaker">IP > Ksp</button>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <button id="middle" type="button" class="btn btn-primary beaker">IP = Ksp</button>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>


  <button id="reset" type="button" class="btn btn-primary beaker">IP < Ksp</button>

</div>
```

**Output Resized**

[image]

Comment: the button does change accordingly to screen size adjustments but the text inside it doesnt follow the button size.. so it is out of the button when the buttons gets small

Comment: @NurShaherra i checked on chrome it's working fine. you can also try like `0.90em` for font.

Answer (score 0):

why don't u try to use media? You only need to set the width and height. Then, when you resize your screen. The button's size will change too

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be good to use Bootstrap.
when you use bootstrap, it is easy to manage size of Button.

you can use md, sm ,xs, lg for button class.